# Multiselect Widget to SQL Query

Tags: sql

I am trying to make a SQL Query to a Database with the inputs obtained from a Multiselect Widget.

The input of the Widget just mentioned is:

`{{Inputs.selectedDisplayValues}} = January, February            #No parentheses or quotes`

In a database I want to make a Query in the Month column, requesting that it only give me the information of the months that are obtained from the widget. But this causes a Syntax Error.

The SQL that isn't working is:

`Select month, status FROM Database WHERE mes IN ('{{Inputs.selectedDisplayValues}}')`

Equivalent to

`Select month, status FROM Database WHERE mes IN ('January, February')`

The desired result is to fix the array ('January, February') to finally be ('January', 'February')

Comment: Tag the question with the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since string splitting differs among various db vendors, you should specify your db vendor to target help more precisely.

In Postgres, the IN clause could be rewritten to:

```
... IN (select m from regexp_split_to_table(' January, February ','\s*,\s*|^\s*|\s*$') as u(m));
```

The regexp trims whitespace. In case when no unnecessary whitespace was guaranteed, `string_to_array` would suffice.

Comment: @cavezonk This can be simplified to `= any (regexp_split_to_array(' January, February ','\s*,\s*|^\s*|\s*$'))